# a = a + b-->cannot convert from int to char. a+=b-->pass

Tags: java, arrays

hi there now I got a situation here.

```
String myStrings = new String();
myStrings = "10.42.0.1";
char[] charNum = myStrings.toCharArray(); //convert string to char array
char checkSum = 0;
```

A：

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) { 
    checkSum += charNum[i]; 
}
```

B：

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) { 
     checkSum ＝ checkSum ＋charNum[i]; 
}
```

compile A: works just what I expect

compile B: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char

Since I know java will convert `a+=b` to `a=char(a+b)` implicitly, that why A works fine.
But what really concern me is what's wrong with `charNum[i]`. ok, HeadFirstJava tells me
that array is an object, so `charNum[i]` is a reference variable(4bytes), and I accept that. And `charNum[i]`(reference variable) points to an `char`(2bytes), and I want to use that `char`(2bytes) to do arithmetical operation, but it looks like JAVA says NO. When I type

```
checkSum ＝ checkSum＋charNum[i];
( 2bytes )   =  ( 2bytes )  +      ( 4bytes )
```

it means that `charNum[i]` have 4bytes in memory, and it really confuse me, because I use `char`(2bytes) to do the math, not `charNum[i]`(reference variable). And if it really use `charNum[i]`(4bytes, reference variable) to do the math, why do I get the right value of checksum? SO can anyone tell me do I mistaken HeadFirstJava or do I miss some concept here?

And if you can explain this in detail, that would be highly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis - before you comment, you should read what he is asking for (he pointed out he knows about it)

Comment: The diadic `+` operator always returns at least an `int`-wide result.

Comment: (This has nothing to do with the fact that one operand is an array element.  The same would happen with two `char` variables.)

Comment: @libik But he doesn't understand why `checkSum ＝ checkSum＋charNum[i];` doesn't work and that is explained in the various answers.

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis - the question you are pointing him out is NOT what he is asking for, therefore you are wrong and you should not point him to it.

Comment: @libik To respond to someone use `@their-name`. I'm not here to hold anyone's hand. The linked answer holds or links to all the information needed to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in *binary numeric promotion*.  All operand are promoted to the type of the wider operand, and up to at least `int`.  This is described by the [JLS, Section 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - Otherwise, **both operands are converted to type int**.

(emphasis mine)

Therefore a `char` (`checkSum`) plus a `char` (`charNum[i]`) is an `int`.

Comment: ok, now i got that, thanks u guys.                                        DON'T THINK JAVA IN C

Answer (score 2):

It is more simple than you think :).

If you add two `char`'s, it creates `int`. Always.

---

And you are not right in few things : The values of cells in `array of char` is `char`, not reference, therefore `charNum[i]` is `char` and it is only 2 bytes width.

Comment: Because diadic `+` "promotes" `char` to `int`.